# Conditional Expectation

Tags: probability

Let $Y \sim$ po$(1)$ and $X|Y=y \sim N(y,1)$ for $y = 0,1,\dots$
Find $E[X]$

Not sure what to do here to be honest, I think I need to use law of total expectation, but not sure how. Obviously $E[X|Y=y] = y$ but I'm not sure how to proceed from there.

I've tried searching for similar questions, but unfortunately I couldn't find any. I apologise if this has already been answered before.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Yes so you have $E[X] = E[E[X|Y]] = E[Y] = ...$

Comment: $${}{}{1}{}{}$$

Comment: Wow yeah, it seems so obvious now, not sure how I missed that...